# How can I access this site as the administrator?

Tags: users, drush

I have a dev site that I cannot access that contains content ad structure I want to extract. To gain access I created a new dev website and copied over the contributed modules and theme I am using. I then imported the database containing the data.  When I go to the custom home page there is no login (I had not yet added it to the panel containing the home page display).  To access the site, I must do one of two things:

1. Access the site using Drush.  I tried using Drush user-login which returns a link `"http://default/user/reset/1/..."` It is not clear how to use the link.  Using it directly as-is leads to an unknown website search.  Using it as `example.com/default/user/reset/1/...`  leads to a page not found error.  Having never done this before, I am not sure what to expect.
2. If I could change the theme to a standard one such as Bartik through the database or other means I would then have access to a login block.  Where is the current theme stored?

Any other suggestions gratefully accepted:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `default` is substituted for the site name in your drush result, try http://example.com/user/reset/1 which would be the standard password reset page for a user with a `uid` of 1 (the admin user).

If that doesn't work the default theme is set by the `theme_default` variable...you can edit the `variable` table in the database manually and set the value column for that variable to whatever theme you want.

Comment: Once again, thanks! Had the drush link been to http://example... I would have understood better :(  Also, being new to sql, your answer got be reviewing the variables table.  Nice table!

Answer (score 1):

my favorite set of commands :

```
drush sqlq "select name from users where uid=1;"
```

returns a name of the admin user (i tend to set different names for reasons of security and then forget them :)

```
drush upwd admin --password=NewSafePassword
```